# rsync not copying any files

Tags: rsync

I'm running something like the following: `rsync -av -e "ssh" --include="dir1/***" --include="file1.txt" --exclude="*" superuser@remote-server:/var/www/ /var/`, and all I'm getting is the following message:

```
receiving incremental file list

sent 276 bytes  received 10 bytes  21.19 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

And no files are transferring over.

Comment: Where is `dir1` in relation to `/var/www`? What is it that you want to copy? At the moment you would copy the complete `dir1` with contents, and the thing called `file1.txt`, but you would only do that if both `dir1` and `file1.txt` was directly below `/var/www`.

Comment: `dir1` would be at `/var/www/dir1/`; whereas, `file1.txt`,  would be at `/var/www/file1.txt`. I want to copy the `dir1` directory plus everything inside of it recursively. Plus I want `file1.txt` to be copied. And I want to exclude everything else.

Comment: Can you show the output with `-vvv` set?  That will have additional information about which items are included and excluded (and what the filters are set to).

Comment: Are you sure the files are not already on the destination and up to date?  My local tests show that your command should work, and that you get the output that you should get when no files need to be copied.

Answer (score 1):

You are including subdirectories of dir1, but dir1 itself is excluded.  So none of its children are seen.

From the `rsync` man page:

> The concept [of] path exclusion is particularly important when using a
>   trailing '*' rule. For instance, this won't work:
>
> ```
> + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
> + /file-is-included
> - *
> ```
>
> This fails because the parent directory "some" is excluded by the '*' rule, so rsync never visits any of the files in the "some" or
>   "some/path" directories. One solution is to ask for all directories in
>   the hierarchy to be included by using a single rule: "+ */" (put it
>   somewhere before the "- *" rule), and perhaps use the
>   `--prune-empty-dirs` option. Another solution is to add specific include rules for all the parent dirs that need to be visited. For instance,
>   this set of rules works fine:
>
> ```
> + /some/
> + /some/path/
> + /some/path/this-file-is-found
> + /file-also-included
> - *
> ```

Comment: I tried something like that following but it's copying everything instead of specific files and folders: `rsync -av -e "ssh" --prune-empty-dirs --include="*/" --include="dir1/***" --include="file1.txt" --exclude="*" superuser@remote-server:/var/www/ /var/`

Comment: The `dir/***` pattern will match the directory itself and its contents. This is not the issue.